# Rotating a two-dimensional array by 90 degrees in MPI

Tags: arrays, matrix, parallel-processing, rotation, mpi

What I need to do is to rotate 2-d array by 90 degrees (3x3 on 3 processors, 4x4 on 4 etc. ) using derived datatypes in `MPI`. I found that using `Alltoall` function in C on array:

```
[ 1][ 2][ 3][ 4]
[ 5][ 6][ 7][ 8]
[ 9][10][11][12]
[13][14][15][16]
```

I'll get data distributed like this:

```
1:[ 1][ 5][ 9][13]
2:[ 2][ 6][10][14]
3:[ 3][ 7][11][15]
4:[ 4][ 8][12][16]
```

What should I do next (what steps should I take) to collect this vectors as an array on one processor (root) in proper order (order that reflects 90 degrees rotation)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally figured out how it should be done by using [Alltoallv](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Alltoallv.html) and [Gather](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Gather.html) functions.
`Alltoallv` let me to distribute data among processes in reverse order:

```
0:[ 4][ 8][12][16]
1:[ 3][ 7][11][15]
2:[ 2][ 6][10][14]
3:[ 1][ 5][ 9][13]
```

then I used `Gather` to collect the data on `rank 0` process into a buffer:

```
...
//size is a number of processors
MPI_Type_vector(size, 1,1, MPI_INT, &vec ); 
MPI_Type_commit( &vec );

if(rank==0){
int buffer[size*size];
//recv is a name of an array with data on every processor
MPI_Gather(recv,1,vec, buffer, size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
}else{
MPI_Gather(recv,1,vec,NULL,0,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
...
```

as a result I received:

```
[ 4][ 8][12][16]
[ 3][ 7][11][15]
[ 2][ 6][10][14]
[ 1][ 5][ 9][13]
```

Answer (score 1):

The operation you are looking for is called `Transpose`
I will give you the pseudo code to transpose a square matrix of length N by N

```
int matrix[N][N];

for (n=0; n<N-1; ++n)
    for (m=n+1; m<N; ++m)
        swap matrix[n][m] with matrix[m][n]
```

This is pretty efficient as it does the operation in-place. However as I stated this is for a square matrix. You can probably use this to figure out how to do it for a rectangular matrix.